# Replace space with character only after specific words in powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell

Scenario is to replacing the space with some special character, but changes should be be happen only at few positions where the particular word will match.

**For Example**

**string** : `"$my name is $your name is"`

Required output is : (so space replace with `"="`,only after the word whose starting character is `"$"`)

```
"$my=name is $your=name is"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'$my name is $your name is' -replace "(\$[a-z]+)\s","$1="
```

(\$[a-z]+) matches a dollar sign followed by at least one a-z in lowercase and stores it as $1. \s means it must be followed by a space. $1= is the replacement string. It means the part that matched the regex in parentheses followed by the equals sign.

Comment: Not getting the result, my execution command is :                                       $out = "$my name is $your name is" -replace "(\$[a-z]+)\s","$1="
Write-Output $out                                                                                        and output is :  name is  name is  (Using powershell ISE)

Comment: The $my and $your are being replaced with empty strings. The first set of quotes needs to be single quotes. I will fix it.

Comment: You can also replace [a-z]+ with \w, like in the other answer. It is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks Patric - actually my input string was in double quotes,result come after coverting into single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"$my name is $your name is" -replace "(\$\w+)\s",'$1='
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwE63Y/1)

Comment: Yes that's what I am looking for, thanks for sharing the demo as well.Don't know why in powershell it's showing only that much output -